# How to properly implement RabbitMQ RPC from Java servlet web container?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, rabbitmq, thread-local

I'd like for incoming Java servlet web requests to invoke RabbitMQ using the RPC approach as described [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html).

However, I'm not sure how to properly reuse callback queues between requests, as per the RabbitMQ tutorial linked above creating a new callback queue per every request is inefficient (RabbitMQ may not cope even if using the [Queue TTL feature](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl)).

There would generally be only 1-2 RPC calls per every servlet request, but obviously a lot of servlet requests per second.

I don't think I can share the callback queues between threads, so I'd want at least one per each web worker thread.

My first idea was to store the callback queue in a ThreadLocal, but that can lead to memory leaks.

My second idea was to store them in a session, but I am not sure they will serialize properly and my sessions are currently not replicated/shared between web servers, so it is IMHO not a good solution.

My infrastructure is Tomcat / Guice / Stripes Framework.

Any ideas what the most robust/simple solution is?

Am I missing something in this whole approach, and thus over-complicating things?

Note 1- This question relates to the overall business case described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397787/how-to-properly-throttle-web-requests-to-external-systems) - see option 1.

Note 2 - There is a seemingly related question [How to setup RabbitMQ RPC in a web context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797357/how-to-setup-rabbitmq-rpc-in-a-web-context), but it is mostly concerned with proper shutdown of threads created by the RabbitMQ client.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  How did you solve it?